# Redis Index takes too long to take into account the keys I have in my redis server

Tags: redis, stream, jedis, redisearch, redisjson

I only get a part of the data that seems to correspond to the query and each time I requery the data , I get more and more results ,I am using TIMEOUT 0 but the issue persists , and I have no idea as to why Redis has this behaviour.I am not modifying the data at all , but it seems that the index takes too long to analyze all the data in my redis serer , so each time I run the ft.info on my redis index , the number of documents keeps increasing , until it reaches the exact number of documents I have in my redis server (~800k keys ) .

I need the index creation and querying to be under 5 minutes , but just the index creation takes literally more than 2 hours which is absurd .Can anyone please help ?

here is how I created my index :

----> FT.CREATE idx:trdat STOPWORDS 0 ON HASH PREFIX 1 Forex schema tradeDate TAG portfolio TAG